# GLSL: More Efficient Call to texture For Multiple sampler2D Variables

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I am working on a LWJGL project and I am texturing my terrain using a blend map. Here is a very simple example:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 fsh_in_normal;
in vec2 fsh_in_coords;
in vec2 fsh_in_scaled;

out vec4 fsh_out_color;

uniform sampler2D blend_map;
uniform sampler2D texture_1;
uniform sampler2D texture_2;

void main(void) {

   vec4 blend_vec = texture(blend_map, fsh_in_coords);

   vec4 color_tx1 = texture(texture_1, fsh_in_scaled);
   vec4 color_tx2 = texture(texture_2, fsh_in_scaled);

   fsh_out_color = mix(color_tx1, color_tx2, blend_vec.r);

}
```

`fsh_in_scaled` is a scaled version of `fsh_in_coords` so the actual applied textures are seen at a better resolution on screen.

Now here is my question: `texture_1` and `texture_2` have identical image formats and sizes (512x512). So, when I sample them with the same coordinates isn't the computer doing identical calculations for each call to `texture(...)` until the color from the texture is actually sampled? Or does the compiler somehow optimize this on its own?

If it is not optimized, is there a way to streamline the two `texture(...)` calls to make the code more efficient? I do plan on adding at least two more textures to the blend map in the future and they would be of the same dimensions and format as the existing `texture_1` & `texture_2`.

Comment: The main cost here is the actual texture fetch from memory. Don't worry about it unless your fragment shader is actually slow enough (and measure it!) that you need to make things faster.

Comment: Is there a way to make things faster tho? Even if it doesnt matter much at all itd still be interesting to know @DietrichEpp

Comment: The first step when you want to make something faster is to measure how fast it is, and what's the slow part. Start there.

Comment: Alright makes sense. I'll come back to this if it seems to be a problem down the road. Thanks for the help! @DietrichEpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texture sampling is done through hardware texture units, so there is no way to optimize it further. The main cost of texture lookup is in memory access, so you may consider mipmapping to avoid cache misses.

Comment: I did generate mipmaps as well. The performance itself isn't an issue right now, just trying to save wasted gpu computations if at all possible to allow for more complicated lighting and such down the road